# Changing the assets directory in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm working on a project that was created using the vue cli 3.0. And on creation a `src/assets` folder is also made. This folder can include some images for example.

Is it possible to change the path of the assets to something different?

I tried changing the `assetsDir` setting in `vue.config.js`. But this only changes the output path in the build.

Edit:

I should note that I would like to load assets based on a "vendor" environment variable. So if I set this to `vendorX` it should load `src/assets/vendorX` and with `vendorY` it should load `src/assets/vendorY`.

Edit 2:

It appears that the directory name doesn't matter to the Vue Cli. I changed the `assets` folder name to `vendors`. But my guess is that Vue includes all resources files in `src` by default. So I'm now looking for a way to change this, or maybe find a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the assets folder was setup with an alias, that would be found in `webpack.config`, however the vue-cli appears to create a project with hardcoded paths to the assets. Try changing the `src` path for your assets across all files to `./assetsDir/myImg.png`.

Comment: Do you mean renaming the assets folder? Or do you mean changing the references from `@/assets/......` to `@/assetsDir/.....`. I tried the last suggestion, but that gives me a compile error `the dependency was not found`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to access an asset in the arbitrary folder from your Vue SFC / template files using webpack alias.

Assume you have the following line in some of your SFC:

```html
<!-- I would like to access the logo that is located at the  -->
<!-- "project root/public/assets/images/" -->
<img alt="Vue logo" src="@public/assets/images/logo.png" />
```

Then in your `vue.config.js` have the following code:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@src': path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                '@public': path.join(__dirname, 'public')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The `alias` key is where you configure the aliases. Refer for the details on Vue CLI webpack configuration to its [official docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html).

The aliases defined here can be also used from your JS files.